# Rock Paper Scissors and the !== comparison

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wanted to try using the `!==` conditional. Why does this code log 'Invalid choice' and undefined?

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
    if (userInput !== 'rock' || userInput !== 'paper' || userInput !== 'scissors') {
        console.log('Invalid choice');
    } else {
        return userInput;
    }
};

console.log(getUserChoice('paper'));
```

I wanted to try the !== instead of === if statement for a rock paper scissors game. Is the issue syntax or logic?

Comment: Because || is or. so when it asks is it not rock OR paper OR scissors - its not rock - so invalid choice. Change it to &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition will always be true, regardless of the value of `userInput`:

```
userInput !== 'rock' || userInput !== 'paper' || userInput !== 'scissors'
```

You want to use `&&` instead of `||`, like this:

```
userInput !== 'rock' && userInput !== 'paper' && userInput !== 'scissors'
```

That way, you'll only see `Invalid choice` if `userInput` isn't one of the three allowed values.

Lastly, you're seeing `undefined` because you're logging the output of `getUserChoice`, but `getUserChoice` doesn't return anything when the `if` statement is hit.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I changed the or operators to and operators and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `Invalid choice` because of [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation). This means, the logical `OR (||)` expression is evaluated left to right and any of the left values get truthy-value then the rest will not be evaluated.

```js
userInput !== 'rock' || userInput !== 'paper' || userInput !== 'scissors'
```

When `userInput` is equal to `paper` and execute the above condition The first one gets truthy-vaule because `paper` and `rock` are not the same. So that, the rest of them will not be evaluated `(userInput !== 'paper' || userInput !== 'scissors')`. That conditon become true and logged `invalid choice`. And in the condition you didn't return anything so `getUserChoice` function return `undefined`.

Comment: Short circuit evaluation has no influence on the outcome of the expression. Even if all three operands were evaluated, the outcome would still always be true when using the logical OR.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything on the truthy if path, only on the else path.

Also the inverse of `if(x==="a" || x==="b" || ...)` (aka `if(!(...))`) is `if(x!=="a" && x!=="b" && ...)` you need to swap `||` to `&&` and `&&` to `||` too, not just `===` to `!==` and `!==` to `===`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a logical problem. You are asking the code to check if the value submitted by the user if different from 'rock' OR is different from 'paper' OR is different from 'scissor'.

So if you try to insert a good value, like 'paper', the check will pass anyway because 'paper' is anyway different from 'rock' or 'scissor'.

In this case you may want to check if the word passed by the user is different from 'paper' AND 'rock' AND 'scissor'.